# Error messages not getting properly displayed when the fields are left blank?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm a novice in Ajax and jquery.I'm desgining an Ajax form using both of them.Below is the code which i got from google.

I've got two files "form.php" and "process.php" namely. 
This is how it traverses form.php : This form is meant for taking the values and if at all the user fails to enter data it has to show up with an error message it got from "process.php" saying "this field is empty".

Initially,the  orginal version i downloaded from google has only one input field that 
is "name". I customized the form by adding another field called "password". Whenever i click the "submit" button with empty values it shows "name cannot be blank" for both the  fields. Instead it has to be "name cannot be blank" and "password cannot be blank"

Here is code for *form.php*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Ajax Form</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').submit(function(event) { //Trigger on form submit
                //$('#name + .throw_error').empty(); //Clear the messages first
                //$('#success').empty();

                var postForm = { //Fetch form data
                    'name'    : $('input[name=name]').val()
                    'password': $('input[name=password]').val()
                };

                //Store name fields value
                $.ajax({ //Process the form using $.ajax()
                    type        : 'POST', //Method type
                    url         : 'process.php', //Your form processing file url
                    data        : postForm, //Forms name
                    dataType    : 'json',
                    success     : function(data) {
                        if (!data.success) { //If fails
                          if (data.errors.name) { //Returned if any error from process.php
                            $('.throw_error').fadeIn(1000).html(data.errors.name);
                          }
                          else if(data.errors.password)
                          {
                            $('.throw_error').fadeIn(1000).html(data.errors.password);
                          }
                        } 
                        else {
                            $('#success').fadeIn(1000).append(
                              '<p>' + data.posted + '</p>'
                            ); 
                        }
                      }
                });
                event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default submit
            });
          });
         </script>
         <style>
          ul {
            font-family: Arial;
            list-style-type: none;
            }

           #success {
            display: none;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: green;
            margin-left: 85px;
            font-size: 14px;
            }

           input[type=text] {
            padding: 5px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #eee;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            }

           input[type=submit] {
            padding: 3px 8px;
            background: #eee;
            margin-left: 85px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            font-size: 12px;
            }

          .throw_error {
            color:tomato;
            font-size: 12px;
            display: none;
             }

          label {
            font-size: 13px;
            }
      </style>
     </head>
      <body>
       <form method="post" name="postForm">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                <span class="throw_error"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                <span class="throw_error"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
       </form>
    <div id="success"></div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

And here is the *process.php*

```
<?php
$errors = array();    //To store errors
$form_data = array(); //Pass back the data to `form.php`


/* Validate the form on server side */

if(empty($_POST['name'])) { //Name cannot be empty
    $errors['name'] = 'Name cannot be blank';
}

if(empty($_POST['password'])){
    $errors['password'] = 'password cannot be blank';
}

if (!empty($errors)) { //If errors in validation
    $form_data['success'] = false;
    $form_data['errors']  = $errors;
} 
else { //If not, process the form, and return true on success
    $form_data['success'] = true;
    $form_data['posted'] = 'Data Was Posted Successfully';
}

//Return the data back to form.php
echo json_encode($form_data);
```

Comment: This is the format of response which i'm getting {"success":false,"errors":{"name":"Name cannot be blank","password":"password cannot be blank"}}

Comment: You should play nice with [HTTP](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html) and return a meaningful [status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) when there is an error (error code 400 in this case). Then your AJAX call should handle the request error in a separate function (surprisingly called *[error](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)*)

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're using an "else if" for the password error. This block never gets executed if the previous "if" does.  Instead just use two ifs:

```
if(data.errors.name) {
...
}

if(data.errors.password) {
...
}
```

But this probably won't do exactly what you want either because you'll be directly replacing the contents of ".throw_error" each time, and only the latest error will be inside the ".throw_error" element.  Instead you want to make sure you're only populating the related error container.  E.g., given the following markup:

```
<input name="name"/>
<div class="throw_error"></div>

<input name="password"/>
<div class="throw_error_password"></div>
```

You'd have in JS:

```
//for name errors
$(".throw_error").html(data.errors.name);

// for password errors
$(".throw_error_password").html(data.errors.password);
```